# What is the action or filter for adding information under the Permalink in Edit Post/Page?

Tags: filters, actions, post-editor

I would like to add some HTML under the "Permalink:" in the Edit Post/Page page.

Under here:

[image: Under Here]

So what is the action or filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the `edit_form_after_title` action:

```
add_action( 'edit_form_after_title', function(){
    echo '<hr/><div>My custom HTML</div><hr/>';
});
```

to add your custom HTML after the permalink:

[image: custom HTML]

It will inject the HTML between `div#titlediv` and `div#postdivrich`:

```
<div id="post-body-content">
    <div id="titlediv">...<!-- /titlediv -->

       <hr><div>My custom HTML</div><hr>

     <div id="postdivrich" class="postarea edit-form-section">...</div>
     ...
</div>
```

Tip: when you have question like this, best thing to do is look at source code.

The file responsible to output post edit page in admin is `/wp-admin/edit-form-advanced.php`

The hook you are looking for is **`'edit_form_after_title'`** as you can see at [line #476 of that file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NWoUA.gif).

Comment: Your answer is prettier, I merged the mine in this. (and +1)

Comment: nice teamwork, it would be more fair to merge it into your answer ;-)

Comment: I don't think so. I was faster because I typed less and also you made a screenshot, so you worked more, it's fair you get the points :)